# Is docker container completely isolated with outside of the docker container?

Tags: docker

I wonder whether things like shell script execution can affect on the outside of the container. For example, let's say I want to save some file at the host machine from inside of the container, not using docker volumes or mount. Is that can be done? Or let's say I want to kill a process which is running on the host machine with shell commands from inside of the container. Is that can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible, a docker container environment is completely isolated from the host, the only way to change some files in the host is by mounting a volume from the host to the container, you can kill an external PID but it's not a common practice.

Docker takes advantage of Linux namespaces to provide the isolated workspace we call a container. When a container is deployed, Docker creates a set of namespaces for that specific container, isolating it from all the other running containers. The various namespaces created for a container include:

- PID Namespace: Anytime a program starts, a unique ID number is assigned to the namespace that is different than the host system. Each container has its own set of PID namespaces for its processes.
- MNT Namespace: Each container is provided its own namespace for mount directory paths.
- NET Namespace: Each container is provided its own view of the network stack avoiding privileged access to the sockets or interfaces of another container.
- UTS Namespace: This provides isolation between the system identifiers; the hostname and the NIS domain name.
- IPC Namespace: The inter-process communication (IPC) namespace creates a grouping where containers can only see and communicate with other processes in the same IPC namespace.

Containers  allow  developers  to  package  large  or  small amounts  of  code  and  their  dependencies  together  into  an  isolated  package.  This  model  then allows  multiple  isolated  containers  to  run  on  the  same  host,  resulting  in  better  usage  of hardware  resources,  and  decreasing  the  impact  of  misbehaving  applications  on each other and their  host  system.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!! It was really helpful in perspective of expanding my docker knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify host files without mounting them inside the container, though you can mount entire root inside (e.g `-v /:/host`). As for killing host processes, it is possible if you ran the container with `host` [PID mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#pid-settings---pid): `docker run --pid=host ...`.

Comment: to continue on anemyte's answer  you can also check these 2 : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10163 and https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10163

Comment: Thanks for the comment!! It was very intuitive answer for me to comprehend!